# Shape of elements get distorted when scrolling further down the page using 3D animation

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a memory game for mobile and desktop. For flipping the cards I'm making use of 3D animation. The animation looks good on desktop, but when on mobile devices you need to scroll down in order to see the cards. But the further you scroll down the page the more 'distorted' the animation becomes. Here are some gifs visualizing the problem:

- On desktop/larger screens:

  https://gyazo.com/bc0ee776b6b562f00411eda9efff92b5 On mobile devices
- when scrolled down:

  https://gyazo.com/e2e56190b8baffd548427aa8715630b3

My code:

```js
/*----------------------------create list of memory-cards*/
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".memory-card,.memory-card2,.memory-card3"
);

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let lockBoard = false;
/*----------------------------add flip class when card is clicked*/
function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add("flip");

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    /*----------------------------on first click*/
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;

    return;
  }
  /*----------------------------on second click*/
  secondCard = this;

  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let Match = firstCard.dataset.frontface === secondCard.dataset.frontface;


  Match ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener("click", flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener("click", flipCard);
  resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  /*----------------------------if it is not a match:*/
  lockBoard = true; // lock the board

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove("flip");
    secondCard.classList.remove("flip");

    resetBoard(); //unlock board when cards have flipped
  }, 1500); //timeout to see the front face when not a match
}

function resetBoard() {
  [hasFlippedCard, lockBoard] = [false, false];
  [firstCard, secondCard] = [null, null];
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach((card) => {
    let randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24); //Math.random returns random number between 0 and 1 excluding 1, so * 12 to get 12 numbers
    card.style.order = randomPosition;
  });
})(); //IIFE so the cards get shuffled at the start of the game

cards.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener("click", flipCard));
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/games/gam-14/gam1340.cur), auto;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: leaguefont;
  src: url("../fonts/font.ttf");
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("../images/other/background.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


/*--------------------------------------------navbar*/

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 5rem;
}

a {
  font-family: leaguefont;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff9900, #ffff66);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}


/*--------------------------------------------memory card containers*/

.memory-game1,
.memory-game2,
.memory-game3 {
  min-height: 40rem;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 62.5rem;
  max-width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

.memory-game1 {
  width: 40rem;
}

.memory-game2 {
  width: 60rem;
}

.memory-game3 {
  width: 80rem;
}


/*--------------------------------------------memory cards*/

.memory-card,
.memory-card2,
.memory-card3 {
  height: calc(33.333% - 0.625rem);
  margin: 0.313rem;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  min-width: 149px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 0.625rem);
}

.memory-card2 {
  width: calc(16.666% - 0.625rem);
}

.memory-card3 {
  width: calc(12.5% - 0.625rem);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0.513rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1c7ccc, #00ccff);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/*--------------------------------------------click animation*/

div.memory-card:active,
div.memory-card2:active,
div.memory-card3:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.memory-card.flip,
.memory-card2.flip,
.memory-card3.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/*--------------------------------------------Footer*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3.75rem 0rem;
  font-family: leaguefont;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff9900, #ffff66);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}


/*--------------------------------------------Media queries*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  a {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>League of Memory</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script defer src="assets/js/cards.js"></script>
</head>
<!-------------------------------------------------navbar-->
<nav>
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">level one</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="leveltwo.html">level two</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="levelthree.html">level three</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<body>
  <!-----------------------------------------------memory cards (12)-->
  <section class="memory-game1">
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Caitlyn">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/caitlyn.png" alt="Caitlyn" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Caitlyn">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/caitlyn.png" alt="Caitlyn" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Darius">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/darius.png" alt="Darius" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Darius">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/darius.png" alt="Darius" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Ezreal">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/ezreal.png" alt="Ezreal" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Ezreal">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/ezreal.png" alt="Ezreal" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Gangplank">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/gangplank.png" alt="Gangplank" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Gangplank">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/gangplank.png" alt="Gangplank" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Graves">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/graves.png" alt="Graves" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Graves">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/graves.png" alt="Graves" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Katarina">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/katarina.png" alt="Katarina" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Katarina">
      <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/katarina.png" alt="Katarina" />
      <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <div>
      <a href="index.html">
            RESET
            </a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a way to make the animation consistent across the different screen sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should wrap each card in another div and apply the `perspective` property to that:

```html
<div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Katarina">
    <img class="front-face" src="assets/images/champions/katarina.png" alt="Katarina" />
    <img class="back-face" src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png" alt="League Logo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.card-wrapper {
  perspective: 62.5rem;
}
```

If you apply the perspective to the cards' common parent, each card will have a different distance to the perspective origin. Giving each card its own origin should fix your issue.

Comment: I see what you mean and it is working. But it also messes up the memory card's height https://gyazo.com/5d666bb406e5431e049b2616abadfb6b and for some reason the JS Shuffle function also stops working.

Comment: @Kris well the cards have a height calculated using a percentage of some parent container's height. Introducing a new parent element will change this relation and you have to adapt the rest of your code. I just pointed toward a solution for the specific problem, incorporating that into your application is up to you.